# How to assign a random value to a constant so that it does not change its value

Tags: java, random

I wanted to generate a random number using Random() and make it unchanged with-in a given execution irrespective of number of calls to that method.

How can I do it?

The following explanation would make my question more clear.

I am generating a randomNumber within a range by the following method.

```
        private int generateARandomNumber(int min, int max) {
//        min = 101;
//        max = 10001;
        Random random = new Random();
        myRandomNum = random.nextInt(max - min) + min ;
        return myRandomNum;
    }
```

How can I assign the value returned to a constant like

```
MYID = generateARandomNumber(101,10001),
```

which will remain unchanged for this execution?

Comment: Besides making MYID `final`?

Comment: *"How can I assign the value returned to a constant like"* - you should assign it while declaring your constant. *Reminder:* to make a field to be a constant, you need to mark it with modifier `final`.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the constant and make it final:

```java
final int MYID = generateARandomNumber(101, 10001);
```

Final variables cannot be changed after being assigned (similar to “let” statements in other programming languages).